# php executes in browser but fails in cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to create a demo website for users to test. I want to restore the databse every x hours. When I run the php script in browser it works. It drops the tables and restores the databse without any issues. When I add the same file in cron, the tables are dropped but it does not restore the databse. I am not sure why it's not restoring the database.

```
<?php 

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
$mysqli->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES"))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $mysqli->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$row[0]);
    }
}

$mysqli->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');

echo "Deleted databse";

sleep(5);


$sqlScript = file('demo.sql');
foreach ($sqlScript as $line)   {
    
    $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0 ,2);
    $endWith = substr(trim($line), -1 ,1);
    
    if (empty($line) || $startWith == '--' || $startWith == '/*' || $startWith == '//') {
        continue;
    }
        
    $query = $query . $line;
    if ($endWith == ';') {
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die('<div class="error-response sql-import-response">Problem in executing the SQL query <b>' . $query. '</b></div>');
        $query= '';     
    }
}
$mysqli->close();

echo '<div class="success-response sql-import-response">SQL file imported successfully</div>';
?>
```

Cron job

```
*/10    *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/demo/public_html/db.php
```

Comment: Cron jobs either run relative to the home of the user running it, or the server root if it's using `/etc/cron`. `file('demo.sql');` is looking for a relative file path to where the script is being run from, so it will fail when being run by cron

Comment: what @aynber wrote + configure cron properly so you get the output - that is including errors / diagnostic messages - by email automatically. this is standard cron functionality and useful for unattended execution which is crons job. Here PHP would have told you in a warning that the SQL file could not be loaded - at least the educated guess.

Comment: Why do that with php at all instead of loading an appropriate sql file with mysql directly ..?

Comment: Also make sure you have the right permissions to execute it(most likely for user `www-data`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[aynber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007220/aynber) provided the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74537855/php-executes-in-browser-but-fails-in-cron-job/74538027#comment131576322_74537855)

> Cron jobs either run relative to the home of the user running it, or the server root if it's using `/etc/cron`. `file('demo.sql');` is looking for a relative file path to where the script is being run from, so it will fail when being run by cron

I updated the sql file path and it worked.

Comment: There was no answer to accept - the thanks were to the answer provided in the comment (which can't be accepted), not to another answer (which can). In this instance the correct action would be to click "looks ok", "edit" (which is what I did), or to skip. The OP has done the right thing by converting a comment to an answer (with attribution).

Comment: I've made it more obvious that that's what's happened by editing the answer a bit, but from the Low quality answers reviews page it should be clear what's happening as (a) the OP has posted the answer, (b) the OP is thanking another user, (c) the user being thanked had commented on the question, (d) there isn't an "Other answers" link on the review page. If this answer got deleted then we would have no way of knowing what helped the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, in your script there is a relative path. Therefore you need to run it from the directory where script is. You can simply replace the cron command to this:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/demo/public_html/ && /usr/local/bin/php /home/demo/public_html/db.php
```

&& means after applying the first command, apply the following command.

Comment: The issue was with the demo.sql file path.

Comment: Correct, to fix that you also can change the cron job code. It would solve as well.